# How can I fix an error for knitting Rmarkdown to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a project for my thesis using markdown library and I am getting an error when I want to knit my document.

[image]

Does anyone have any thought about this? I am pretty sure there is no equation which needs dollar sign.

I got this error after I changed some texts and nothing else like adding a code or something.

Comment: It seems to be related to a table - without any code it is difficult to help.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: "I got this error after I changed some texts and nothing else": undo the changes.  Knit the document once again.  Does the error go away?